# What does the usage of "that" here mean?

Tags: pronouns, exam-questions

I'm very confused about this sentence now. It's one of answer choices of GRE test. The question is:

Q: The passage suggests that Glass’s work displays which of the following qualities?

Choice B: **An attempt to elevate rock music to an artistic status more closely approximating *that* of classical music.**

What does the usage of "that" here mean? Which is correct if I complete the full sentence here?

1. Does it mean "the attempt"? Seems like not sensible.

An attempt to elevate rock music to an artistic status more closely
approximating the attempt of classical music.

2. Does it mean "an attempt to elevate rock music to an artistic status"? But this would seem to redundant.
3. Does it mean "An attempt to elevate rock music"? Then it should be "that to" instead of "that of", right?

Comment: that = artistic status. "An attempt to elevate rock music to an artistic status more closely approximating (the artistic status) of classical music."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*that* is a [relative pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_pronoun), whose antecedent is "artistic status".  Read it like this:

```
An attempt to elevate rock music to an artistic status more
closely approximating (the artistic status) of classical music.
```

> Does it mean "an attempt to elevate rock music to an artistic status"? But this would seem to (be) redundant.

This is saying that classical music is given more status than rock music, as "serious art".  The attempt is to raise the status level of rock, so it can be closer to classical's status level.

Comment: ^vote with a note: I'd go further and say that the test sentence is poorly written. "An artistic status more closely approximating" is sloppy writing, probably ungrammatical. No wonder the poster had a problem with it.

Comment: @hmmn I don't see any problem with it as a sentence, seems entirely typical.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it!! It really helps me a lot because there are so many sentences used like this. I have another one to ask too.

Comment: "In the United States between 1850 and 1880, the number of farmers continued to increase, but at a rate lower than that of the general population." "That" here means "the number of farmers"? So does it mean "The proportion of farmers in the United States labor force decreased"?

Comment: An  attempt to elevate rock music to artistic music that more closely  approximates to (of is rarely used) classical music. "That" is a relative pronoun. But the poster's sentence is  incomplete. So is mine. There should be something like they made an attempt  to....

Comment: @Khan It's the A: on a Q: and A of a multiple choice question, implied to be substituted into: *The passage suggests that Glass’s work displays _____*

Comment: I would not call "that" a relative pronoun here, as there is no relative clause. I would call it a _resumptive pronoun_. Syntactically it can always be replaced by a repetition of the original noun phrase but with a definite article. (Here "... to an artistic status more closely approximating the artistic status of ... "). A relative pronoun cannot be so replaced, as it is doing more syntactically than just standing in for a noun phrase.

Comment: @LuluCailoo: "but at a rate lower than _the rate (of increase)_ of the general population". So it means the proportion increased, but not as fast as the general population increased. Again, _that_ replaces the noun phrase immediately before the comparison - "lower than" or "approximating".

Comment: The test sentence would have been clearer as "... status more approximate to ..." rather than "... status more closely approximating ...." Gerunds are familiar, true, but they easily muddle sentence structure and can be ambiguous in other ways as well. In this case, *satus* is a quality, whose active role in approximat*ing* something would be more appropriate in poetry than a verbal reasoning test.